# I'm getting an erro at jspInit() and at jspDestroy()

Tags: eclipse, jsp

there is some Syntax error showing on token "jspInit", AnnotationName expected after this token and Syntax error showing on token "jspDestroy", AnnotationName expected after this token.

```
 <% connection con;
   public void jspInit() {
     try{
      Class.forName("Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","tiger"); 
      }  
    catch(SQLException sqle){
     sqle.printStackTrace();
     } 
   }
   public void jspDestroy () {
      try{
       con.close();
       }  
      catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
       }   

  }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i don't recommend to write java code in JSP page.

You need to use declaration syntax `(<%! ... %>):` not scriptlet

```
 <%! 
       public String yourMethod() { 
          // 
       } 
    %>
```

Your Code should be like this

```
<%!
    Connection con;
    public void jspInit() {

        try{
            Class.forName("Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","tiger");
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle){
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void jspDestroy () {
        try{
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle){
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods (`jspInit()` and `jspDestroy()` in your case) have to be defined in a **declarations** block, not in a scriptlet. I.e. `<%!` instead of just `<%`.

```
<%! connection con;
  public void jspInit() {
  // ...
  }
%>
```